# Macro to remove double quotes in c

Tags: c, macros

Is there any macro which will remove double quotes and '\0' in a string?

For example:-
"HELLO\0" -> HELLO

Edited:-
Actually I want to get the function address. So I thought to use **FUNC** Macro to get the function name and stipping out double quotes and '\0' will help me to get the function address.

for ex:

```
#define FUN_PTR fun
#define FUN_NAME "fun"
void fun(){
 printf("fun add %p name %s\n",FUN_PTR,FUN_NAME);
}
```

To avoid user define macros. I like to know other methods to derive these functionality :).

```
void fun(){
 printf("fun add %p name %s\n",<SOME_MACRO>(__FUNC__),__FUNC__);
}
```

Comment: Why? Maybe there's another way to do what you want ...

Comment: Ok, what exactly are you trying to do here?  Seems like if we had a larger idea of the problem domain, we could give a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it the other way around.

```
#define PRINT_PTR(p) printf(#p " == %p\n", (void *) p)

int main()
{
    PRINT_PTR(exit);
    return 0;
}
```

Inside a macro, if `x` is a macro argument, then `#x` is the string version.

```
#define PRINT_INT(i) printf(#i " == %d\n", i)
PRINT_INT(5 + ~3);
PRINT_INT(atoi("1234"));
```

Typically, if you use this a lot, then you'll want to define a helper function to work around the weak type system in C:

```
void print_ptr_func(char const *s, int v);
#define PRINT_PTR(p) print_ptr_func(#p, p)
```

Note that this won't work for getting the address of the current function.  `__FUNC__` is not a macro and it is not a string literal, it has no double quotes.  You cannot use `__FUNC__` to get the address of the function without some serious trickery, and it will break half the time.  For example:

```
#define PRINT_FUNC_INFO() print_func_info(__FUNC__)

#include <dlfcn.h>
void print_func_info(char const *n)
{
    void *p = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, n);
    printf("Function %s, address %p\n", n, p);
}
```

However, this will not work half the time -- `dlsym` wasn't designed to be used for that purpose.